# Does it have a better way when using try...except in with statement?

Tags: python, with-statement

With statement is a good feature in python. However in my work, I often meet some cases like this:

```
with with_function() as wf:
    try:
        wf.a_method()
    except wf_exception as exc:
        # processing code
        ....
```

or will use more `try...except` inside the `with` block.

`with_function` is defined in the bottom of the project and may not be changed!

But in practice, most cases are I just need to log the exception to let it go instead of raising it in `with_function`.

Does it have a better way or create a new function with contextmanager to process?

Comment: So what should happen when an exception occurs? Can the context manager be made responsible for that?

Comment: The short answer is *it depends*. What is `with_function` and what do its `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods do? Does it handle `wf_exception` itself?

Comment: the `with` statement only handles  exceptions in `__enter__` and `__exit__` of your context manager (e.g. opening/closing a file). if `a_method()` can raise an exception it is good practice to enclose it in a `try/except` block.

Comment: although the with_function help process a lot of exceptions, but in my occasion，most cases is I need just log the special exception defined in the project.@MartijnPieters   @jonrsharpe

Comment: @Octavian: then those are your options. Your question is otherwise too open-ended and vague to be answerable here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have already put more statements in my question to narrow the answer I want.

Comment: @Octavian: reopened; but why not make the existing context manager responsible still? You could make it a flag, for example.

Comment: In [contextlib](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/contextlib.py) , it will raise even in the definition of with_function. But I run the code in a script. It is better not to process it and log the exception than to stop it. And what does make it flag mean? Sorry, I don't really catch your idea.@MartijnPieters